# Use of until/till

Tags: meaning

I usually get confused while using those words.......

For example: "The producers already confirmed that Bran Stark and his associated storyline will not reappear until Season 6."

Here,will Bran Stark come in season 6 or after season 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means Stark will [probably] appear again in season 6.

compare:

- will reappear in Season 6
  (means exactly that)
- will **not** reappear in Season 6
  (he might appear later, but not in Season 6)
- will **not** reappear **until** Season 6 
  (implies, but does not guarantee, that he will appear in Season 6. But it is certain he will not appear before then.)
- will **not** reappear **until** Season 6 **at the earliest** (he is expected to reappear, possibly in Season 6 or possibly in a later season)
- will reappear **by** Season 6 (he will return in Season 6, or possibly earlier, but no later than Season 6)